# Replicate the data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have some data in a dataframe `df` whose length is `n` and I am creating a larger dataframe `dg` whose length is say `10n`. I want to copy data from `df` to `dg` so that the rows in `dg` would be periodically filled by the data in `df`. I tried following:

```
dg = pd.DataFrame(index = range(10*n), columns = columns)

for i in range(0, 10*n, n):
    for j in range(n):
        dg[col][i : i+n] = df[col][0:n]
```

However, this is extremely slow. Is there any faster way to achieve the same? Ideally, I would love to see a solution in which I can simply take `df` and extend its length to 10n so that all the data would simply be copied periodically.

Comment: you want each row to repeat n times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't care about order then this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({"data": [1,2]})
df = pd.concat([x]*5, ignore_index=True)
df
```

output:

```
    data
0   1
1   2
2   1
3   2
4   1
.
.
```

if you care about the order then you can go with this approach:

```
import numpy as np
df = x.loc[np.repeat(x.index.values, 3)]
df
```

output:

```
    data
0   1
0   1
0   1
1   2
1   2
1   2
```

Comment: Thanks. I found out the same in the meantime :)

Comment: @Peaceful np :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 5), columns=list('abcde'))
df

          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
1  0.016545  0.850445  0.817744  0.777962  0.757983
2  0.934829  0.831104  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535
3  0.117642  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702
```

## `pandas`

Using `iloc`

```
r = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(3)
df.iloc[r].reset_index(drop=True)

           a         b         c         d         e
0   0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
1   0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
2   0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
3   0.016545  0.850445  0.817744  0.777962  0.757983
4   0.016545  0.850445  0.817744  0.777962  0.757983
5   0.016545  0.850445  0.817744  0.777962  0.757983
6   0.934829  0.831104  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535
7   0.934829  0.831104  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535
8   0.934829  0.831104  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535
9   0.117642  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702
10  0.117642  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702
11  0.117642  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702
```

## `numpy`

```
r = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(3)
pd.DataFrame(df.values[r], columns=df.columns)

           a         b         c         d         e
0   0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
1   0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
2   0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
3   0.016545  0.850445  0.817744  0.777962  0.757983
4   0.016545  0.850445  0.817744  0.777962  0.757983
5   0.016545  0.850445  0.817744  0.777962  0.757983
6   0.934829  0.831104  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535
7   0.934829  0.831104  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535
8   0.934829  0.831104  0.879891  0.926879  0.721535
9   0.117642  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702
10  0.117642  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702
11  0.117642  0.145906  0.199844  0.437564  0.100702
```

---

***time test***

[image]